# NsMutableAttributed string swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I am working on editor app in swift.

For editor I use an attributed string and I am getting a random error when cut and paste text.

This is the error :

`-[NSBigMutableString characterAtIndex:]: Index 3369 out of bounds; string length 3367'`

I am using this code for attributed string .

```
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

    if (text.characters.count == 0 && range.length == 1) {
        return true
    }
    if !isBold {
       let size = CGFloat(Float(lblFontSize.text!)!)
  let boldFont: UIFont = UIFont(name: "MinwalaNastaleeq-checking", size: size)!
        let boldAttr: [String : AnyObject] = [
            NSFontAttributeName : boldFont,
            NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : titleParagraphStyle,
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName : textColor
        ]
        let attributedText: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text, attributes: boldAttr)
       textView.replaceRange(textView.selectedTextRange!, withText: text)
        let textViewText: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: textView.attributedText)

        textView.attributedText = textViewText
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't you simply use .uppercaseString? to convert it to capital letters

Comment: But i don't need to use uppercaseString . in my case i worked on urdu text.

Comment: Could it be related to the encoding used to get length between `NSString` and `String` that may differ? I think that I saw something related to this somewhere.